# How do I transform python AudioSegment extraction to an ffmpeg command?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, ogg

I have a python script which loads an MP4 file and saves the audio to an OGG file like so:

```
movie = AudioSegment.from_file(f"movie.mp4", format="mp4")
movie.export(f"audio.ogg", format="ogg")
```

I want to extract that to a bash script which will run once at the we create our Debian packages. To do so, I prefer bash and no python. Is the following command equivalent?

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vn audio.ogg
```

It seems to work (the audio sounds the same), but I wanted to make sure that it was as close as possible to the original conversion. The resulting files can't just be compared apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vn audio.ogg
```

- Yes, this will convert the audio in the MP4 to Vorbis audio and put it in OGG container.
- Video will be ignored due to `-vn`.
- This assumes your `ffmpeg` was compiled with `--enable-libvorbis` (it is commonly enabled for distributed ffmpeg packages, such as from your distro). If it's not then `ffmpeg` will fallback to the native, built-in FLAC encoder. You can prevent this by adding the `-c:a libvorbis` output option, and it will instead fail if libvorbis is not available.

Comment: Ah, good idea to add the `-c:a libvorbis`. Now when I compare both files, the one generated by python and the one generated by ffmpeg, the data looks completely different...

Comment: @AlexisWilke If AudioSegment is just a wrapper for the ffmpeg cli tool then you can refer to the log of the ffmpeg process to see what it's doing. Or see [pydub debugging](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#debugging) (I'm assuming you're using pydub but I don't know). You can show the complete output of `ffprobe -show_format -show_streams AudioSegment.ogg` and `ffprobe -show_format -show_streams ffmpeg.ogg` to compare the audio files.